# Using more than one special exception class

Tags: c#, .net, exception

For the software we're developing at the company that I work for, we use a third-party library which is developed by a guy that we're constantly in contact with. His code is written in C++, and we use C# in the project.

Normally, his library functions return error codes. I decided to have different exception classes to cover different ranges of error codes. For example, one exception class for parameter handling errors, one exception class for main operation errors, one exception class for input value errors and so on.

He thinks it's not a good idea, and suggests using one exception class for the library that catches all the errors, and then fetches the error code from an XML file and outputs the problem to the user. He thinks, it's pointless to write more than one exception class. And also he says that he can't promise that the error codes will be the same in different versions of the library.

I think it's a good idea to have more than one exception class because:

1. There may be different situations that we need to handle the problem differently. Maybe when there's a parameter exception, do other stuff than just outputting an error. But he thinks his library is handling everything, and we should just stop the operation and output an error. I also can't think of many concrete examples of cases we need to handle differently, other than showing an error message. But I feel we may need it, and I'm afraid that I'm just violating the YAGNI principle.
2. I think if he turns out wrong, and we need to handle things differently in different cases, I'll have to introduce conditional code (if error was A then do this, if B then do that). And it will be difficult to handle.

I think it's a better idea to develop the program in a way that we can handle different types of exceptions differently. But then the guy has much more experience than me, plus he has much more credibility in the company (I'm a new intern) and I'm pretty new to software development and I feel like maybe he's right and I'm just trying to add extra code because it looks pretty, and violating the YAGNI principle.

Do you think we should go with one class or more? And if you think we should use more than one exception class, what are your reasons?

Comment: ArgumentException, InvalidOperationException, ArithmeticException... these are all present in the .NET Framework - you only need to look at that to decide that there has to be some specifity in the error handling that you implement. Having error codes change meaning in different versions of a library is a nightmare. Working in software for a while has made me realise; it doesn't matter how much xp someone has, they can still be a bad developer or not really know what's best. Having said that, it depends exactly what your application is doing and whether recovering from an error is valid and OK

Comment: @Charleh well, if error codes are constantly changing meaning, it'd be just as difficult to use outside of .Net as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error codes can change from version to version, then no amount of work (or lack of it) is going to save you trouble of having to remap these somehow at some point. If you have exceptions for codes (or code ranges) then it's hardly going to be *much more* work than if you didn't have, when error codes do change (you're going to be rearranging what exceptions are thrown, just as you would have to be jiggling the messages around for one exception if you didn't have dedicated classes).

Besides, in general practice, by .NET convention, you should create a dedicated exception class for specific exceptions that aren't aptly covered by BCL-provided exceptions (excluding use of the some in there that are meant for abstraction only).

For some Microsoft input, consider [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229014%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Applications and libraries should not use return codes to communicate errors.

And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229021%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Consider throwing existing exceptions residing in the System
>   namespaces instead of creating custom exception types.

But, following the [Exception Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229014%28v=vs.100%29.aspx),

> [will] help ensure that you use the existing
>   exceptions, where appropriate, and create new exceptions where they
>   add value to your library.

Stick to your guns.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. It's better to use several exception classes for different types of errors (for different error codes). Exceptions are somewhat successors of error codes, so it's better to use exception. And the approach that guy is offering is again using error codes, wrapped by one exception class.

SqlException with his Number comes on my mind. It's a hell to catch different types of errors by checking error code.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use more than one exception class. Note though that there are a ton of built in classes already made in the `System` namespace such as `ArgumentNull` and friends.

If you want to see a case where multiple exceptions aren't used, take a look at COM interop. It's a dark place with generic exceptions thrown and their reasoning being justified by a single integer `HRESULT`. Trust me, you don't want to recreate that.

One really specific use case though is for instance whenever you just want to catch a certain exception. i.e.

```
try
{
  lib.OpenFile(mypath);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
 //handle gracefully and possibly "ignore" this error 
}
```

Here, you want to do some other action if the file isn't found. However, if `OpenFile` throws an exception because `mypath` is null, you probably want this exception to bubble up and throw an error. (at least so you can log it or something). With a single exception class, this becomes more painful

```
catch(MyException e)
{
  if(e.Reason=10)
  {
  }else{
    throw; //rethrow exception(which makes debugging more difficult)
  }
}
```

Comment: You would just use `throw` in the latter case, to maintain stack trace, rather than re-throwing and losing context.

Comment: @GrantThomas ah, I knew there was something special about rethrowing.. still screws with Visual Studio's debugger though